# Cannot import scitools using Anaconda-Python

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, scitools

I am trying to install [scitools](http://scitools.googlecode.com/hg/doc/easyviz/easyviz.html#fig:quiver3_ex1) with the hope of being able to use Easyviz. I installed scitools for windows as suggested in the first link. However, when I type `from scitools.std import *` into python I get the following error message:

```
ImportError: No module named oldnumeric.mlab
numpy import failed!
see doc of scitools.numpytools module for how to choose Numeric instead
```

This was discussed [here](https://code.google.com/p/scitools/issues/detail?id=33) and categorized as fixed, however I don't see how I can make this work or how to fix it. Is there something I am supposed to do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. However, such issue was not found on Trisquel GNU Linux. 
The solution which I found by randomly testing was - 
Do not import scitools. Just import numpy.

As an example if you were to write - 
`from scitools.std import *`
simply do - 
`import numpy as np`
and use numpy libraries. For plotting use matplotlib that will solve this issue.